# jQuery mouseover to call different function in different context

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here is my problem:

I would like mouseover() to add different css class to my nav buttons when page is scrolled at different places. However it seems mouseover() calls as long as I move the mouse over my buttons, despite I have used an if statement (I used a variable to track the scroll position).

is it possible for mouseover() to call different functions?

e.g.

```
$(".menu").mouseover(function(){
if (scroll_position<300) {
    $(this).addClass("white");
}
else{
    $(this).addClass("blue");
}
});
```

Thanks guys:)

Comment: `if` statements work just fine in `mouseover`.  Perhaps your `scroll_position` variable is not set correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (`$(document).scrollTop()` gives distance to top):

```
$(".menu").mouseover(function(){

    if ($(document).scrollTop()<300) {
        $(this).addClass("white");
    }
    else{
        $(this).addClass("blue");
    }

});
```